# Line segment connectivity analysis in FME

Tags: vector, fme-form, connectivity-analysis

I have a set of line segments, all of them snapped at the endpoints:

[image: Groups of connected lines]

As seen in the above image, the line segments appear in groups (4 in this example).

**Question:**
I would like to determine which line segments are connected to each other and assign an ID (in this example the values 1, 2, 3 or 4) to each line segment describing which group it belongs to. How can I do this in FME?

Comment: Buffer your lines and apply an id based on the dissolved buffer - loosely based on this example http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Dissolving-features-using-the-Dissolver-Transformer

Comment: Exactly what I have done so far. Thanks for *verifying* my solution :)

Comment: @Chau, would you mind posting your solution as an answer so others may benefit?

Comment: Well I would suggest @Mapperz to post his solution as an answer, since the credit should go to him for posting first.

Comment: @Chau did the suggestion solve your question? if yes, will post a full answer.

Comment: @Mapperz: As I stated in a previous comment, you proposed a solution that I already had used - thus verifying my approach. I think its more appropriate that you give the answer. And yes, it worked just fine :)

Comment: I know this is frowned upon but I don't particularly like it when people ask for help, then claim the answer for themselves less than 12 minutes later. Chau you should show some human ettiquette by graciously accepting the response that was posted instead of taking the credit for it. You asked for a solution without offering that you had done a certain thing already, either you just wanted everyone to see how smart you are and didn't really need help or you just can't bear to truly accept help without claiming the credit for it. Next time try being receptive without the annoying "I know, I kno

Comment: I asked a question for which I didn't have an answer. **@Mapperz** came with a comment which is identical to what I had tried in the time *after* (5 hours between question and first comment) posting my question. My veryfing statement was meant as a tribute to **Mapperz** abilities, at least I'm a bit proud that I found a solution that one of the main contributers to this site shortly hereafter proposes. If **Mapperz** has been offended I'm sorry. Your *answer* I really don't see the purpose of and **Mapperz** wrote that he would like to post a full answer.

Comment: @BillKinkaid I would rather put this as a comment and/or try to make a point in another way (maybe pointing to other discussions of a related FAQ, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). I would avoid, however, to _dedicate_ an answer for this.